# Unity URP fog works on scene objects but not loaded assetbundles - why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, fog, assetbundle, urp

I'm using Unity 2021.3.15 LTS with URP, and I'm having trouble with fog. When I create an object in my scene and turn fog on using the Environment tab of the Lighting window, the fog effect works fine. However, when I save that object to an assetbundle, and then load that assetbundle into a scene, fog has no effect on the rendering of the object.

The attached screenshot shows two identical red capsules, both using the same material (URP/Lit shader with red color). The right one has been loaded from an assetbundle and shows no fog. The left capsule was created in the Editor and does exhibit fog effect.
[fog effect difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaa9K.png)

Any insights into why the fog behavior is different between the two would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.